# Use Xpath To Filter Records

Tags: xml, xpath

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I'm using the following script to load images from an XML file into a web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<?php 

  //This variable specifies relative path to the folder, where the gallery with uploaded files is located. 
  //Do not forget about the slash in the end of the folder name. 
  $galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/'; 

  $thumbnailsPath = $galleryPath . 'Thumbnails/'; 

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 

  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml'); 
?>
<head> 
  <title>Gallery</title> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <link href="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <!--[if IE]>   
  <link href="Styles/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="Libraries/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

  $(function() { $('a.fancybox').fancybox(); }); 

  </script> 
  <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}
.style4 {font-size: 12px}
-->
  </style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; font-size: 9px; border-bottom-width: thin; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: -475px; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: -10px;">
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "imagefolders.php" /> View Uploaded Images In Folder Structure <a/> &larr; View All Uploaded Images </div>
  <form id="gallery" class="page"> 
  <div id="container"> 
    <div id="center"> 
      <div class="aB"> 
        <div class="aB-B"> 
          <?php if ('Uploaded files' != $current['title']) :?>
          <?php endif;?>
          <div class="demo"> 
            <div class="inner"> 
              <div class="container"> 
                <div class="gallery"> 
                  <ul class="gallery-image-list"> 
                  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) : 
                          $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i); 
                          $name = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $description = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $folder = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('folder'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $source = $galleryPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('source')); 
                          $thumbnail = $thumbnailsPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('thumbnail')); 
                  ?>
                    <li class="item"> 
                      <a class="fancybox" target="_blank" rel="original" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img class="preview" 
                        alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"  src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" /></a>                      </li>
                        <li class="item"></li>
                        <p><span class="style4"><b>Image Description:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'));?> <br />
                            <b>Image contained in folder:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('folder'));?> </span><br />  
                          <?php endfor; ?>
                          </li>
                    </p>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
        <div class="aB-a">        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Amended Code With XPath - NB Not A Working Solution**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<?php 

  //This variable specifies relative path to the folder, where the gallery with uploaded files is located. 
  //Do not forget about the slash in the end of the folder name. 
  $galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/'; 

  $thumbnailsPath = $galleryPath . 'Thumbnails/'; 

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 

  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');

   $xpath = new DOMXPATH($descriptions);
?>
<head> 
  <title>Gallery</title> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <link href="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <!--[if IE]>   
  <link href="Styles/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="Libraries/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

  $(function() { $('a.fancybox').fancybox(); }); 

  </script> 
  <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}
.style4 {font-size: 12px}
-->
  </style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; font-size: 9px; border-bottom-width: thin; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: -475px; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: -10px;">
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "imagefolders.php" /> View Uploaded Images In Folder Structure <a/> &larr; View All Uploaded Images </div>
  <form id="gallery" class="page"> 
  <div id="container"> 
    <div id="center"> 
      <div class="aB"> 
        <div class="aB-B"> 
          <?php if ('Uploaded files' != $current['title']) :?>
          <?php endif;?>
          <div class="demo"> 
            <div class="inner"> 
              <div class="container"> 
                <div class="gallery"> 
                <ul class="gallery-image-list">  
                  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) : 
                          $name = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@originalname");   
                          $description = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@description");   
                          $folder = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@folder");   
                          $source = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@source");         
                          $thumbnail = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@thumbnail");   
                  ?> 
                    <li class="item">  
                      <a class="fancybox" target="_blank" rel="original" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img class="preview"  
                        alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"  src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" /></a>                      </li> 
                        <li class="item"></li> 
                        <p><span class="style4"><b>Image Description:</b> <?php echo $description;?> <br /> 
                            <b>Image contained in folder:</b> <?php echo $folder;?> </span><br />   

                          </li> 
                        </p> 
            <?php endfor; ?> 
</ul> 
                </div> 
              </div> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
        <div class="aB-a">        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

and this is the XML file which is loaded into the page:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <files>
  <file name="Test 1/_47061196_greatbritainjpg.jpg" source="_47061196_greatbritainjpg.jpg" size="227505" originalname="_47061196_greatbritainjpg.jpg" thumbnail="_47061196_greatbritainjpg.jpg" description="No description provided" userid="1" locationid="1" folder="Test_1" />  
  <file name="Test 1/article-0-07D01B74000005DC-138_468x617.jpg" source="article-0-07D01B74000005DC-138_468x617.jpg" size="143110" originalname="article-0-07D01B74000005DC-138_468x617.jpg" thumbnail="article-0-07D01B74000005DC-138_468x617.jpg" description="No description provided" userid="1" locationid="1" folder="Test_1" /> 
  <file name="Test 1/stags-snow_1544533c.jpg" source="stags-snow_1544533c.jpg" size="21341" originalname="stags-snow_1544533c.jpg" thumbnail="stags-snow_1544533c.jpg" description="No description provided" userid="1" locationid="1" folder="Test_1" /> 
  </files>
```

What I would like to do is to make the images loaded user specific, so for example 'userid' of value '1' at 'locationid' value '1' can only view those images with the matching values in the XML file.

I know from the tutorials and articles I've read that an 'Xpath' statement is able to do this. However there appears to be many different ways to do this, and having very, very, little of XML I'm really not sure where to start.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps offer me some help please to help me to be able to achieve this.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem!

For your xpath statement, I'm assuming you would want to return the filename of whichever  xml node that contains the userid and locationid you need.

So you would first start at the root node , then check which file has this criteria:

locationid and userid are both attributes of , so you need to use the @ symbol when referencing them in xpath.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPATH($descriptions) ; 
$result = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@name");
```

This might look a little confusing since your attribute names are the same as the input names, but the variables in the ". ." are referring to the block:

```
<input name="userid" type="text" id="userid" value="1" />
<input name="locationid" type="text" id="locationid" value="1" />
```

So this would give you the name of the file for that user, which you could apply to your $source  tag. Just repeat the given xpath and append /@description or /@thumbnail in place of name to get the other values.

Hope this helps, let me know if I need to clarify anything!

**Try this:**

(not sure where your input form went in the original code, but if you're still using it:)

```
<ul class="gallery-image-list"> 
                  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) :
                          $name = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@originalname");  
                          $description = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@description");  
                          $folder = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@folder");  
                          $source = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@source");        
                          $thumbnail = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@thumbnail");  
                  ?>
                    <li class="item"> 
                      <a class="fancybox" target="_blank" rel="original" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img class="preview" 
                        alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"  src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" /></a>                      </li>
                        <li class="item"></li>
                        <p><span class="style4"><b>Image Description:</b> <?php echo $description;?> <br />
                            <b>Image contained in folder:</b> <?php echo $folder;?> </span><br />  

                          </li>
                        </p>
            <?php endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying to my post. I've added the line in at the top of my script under `$descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');`, but could you tell m please, am I right in thinking that there is a " missing at the end. The line doesn't appear to be closed in Dreamweaver? Kind regards

Comment: Ah yes, forgot the ending marks, good catch! Sorry about that, I edited my post with the correction.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the confirmation, it was a bit of a guess to be honest :) I'm sorry to be a pain with this, but I've added the line `$result = $xpath->query("files/file[@userid=" . userid . " and @locationid=" . locationid . "]/@name"); ` at line 16 under `$descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml');` but I receive the following error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/gallery.php on line 16`. Could perhaps explain what I've done wrong please?

Comment: Sure, I was mainly trying to show how to do the xpath. I'll update my answer with some of the basic setup. In the meantime, this is a great link for php/xpath combos: [PHP with XPATH](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

Comment: I believe the error is because of your placement of the $result= line, as your <input> variables probably aren't setup yet. Try moving it below the $thumbnail line.

Comment: Hi many thanks for this, and apologies for the confusion. I'll certainly be reading the information in the link. I've moved the line, and although there is no error, instead of the images being shown, I'm just receiving a red cross. Kind regards.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Could you update your original code with what you've added?

Comment: @all - in general once you have a solution, it can be confusing if you add that into your question - since new readers will then wonder why the question doesn't bear any relation to the conversation! Add it in either as an "Edit" section to your question so it is clear it is an addendum, or put it into a new Answer.

Comment: Hi @jdwilemo, sincere thanks for the updated code. Unfortunately when I run this I receive the following error: `<a class="fancybox" target="_blank" rel="original" href=" Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/gallery.php on line 65`. Line 65 is this line `<a class="fancybox" target="_blank" rel="original" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img class="preview"`. Kind regards